# Compilar .NET CLI creando una solución en SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, sharpdevelop

Quiero compilar en *.NET CLI* en *SharpDevelop*.

El repositorio es este: https://github.com/dotnet/cli

Descargué el **master.zip**, luego abriendo el **Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.sln** me da el siguiente error, repetido para cada proyecto de la solución.

> Building project **dotnet** is not supported.

Como no puedo compilarlo, intento abrir el proyecto **dotnet.csproj**, y tengo otro error:

> Can't load file dotnet.csproj under C:\Users\Otecald\Downloads\cli-master\src\dotnet.
>
> Check the file permission and the existence of that file.
>
> The attribute "Remove" in element  is unrecognized.  C:\Users\Otecald\Downloads\cli-master\src\dotnet\dotnet.csproj

Luego le hice caso al error, y quité el `<Compile Remove`, pero salta otro error similar.

Entonces lo que hice fue crear un nuevo proyecto de consola, copiar todos los archivos del proyecto y agregarlos al proyecto nuevo. Reemplazando el **Program.cs**

Cuando voy a compilar saltan 296 errores, el primero es en el archivo **ArgumentForwardingExtensions.cs**

```
namespace Microsoft.DotNet.Cli
{
    public static class ArgumentForwardingExtensions
    {
        public static ArgumentsRule Forward(
            this ArgumentsRule rule) =>
            rule.MaterializeAs(o => new ForwardedArgument(o.Arguments.SingleOrDefault()));
```

El error es el siguiente:

> ; expected (CS1002) - ArgumentForwardingExtensions.cs:11,38
>
> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519) - ArgumentForwardingExtensions.cs:12,31
>
> Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (CS1519) - ArgumentForwardingExtensions.cs:12,34
>
> Method must have a return type (CS1520) - ArgumentForwardingExtensions.cs:12,41
>
> Identifier expected (CS1001) - ArgumentForwardingExtensions.cs:12,86

Veo este operador `=>` y recuerdo las expresiones lambda, quizás es muy nuevo y por eso no está soportado, en verdad no entiendo por qué no compila. ¿Habrá que activar algún flag en alguna parte?

¿Es posible que el código se pueda compilar con *SharpDevelop*? ¿Hay alguna alternativa?

Comment: seguiste los pasos como estan descriptos en el manual?

Comment: @gbianchi No había leído el manual, acabo de leerlo, no dice nada sobre _SharpDevelop_. Descargando el **master.zip** no funciona, tuve que hacer `git clone --recurse-submodules` y luego ejecutar **build.cmd**. De todos modos creo estaría bueno que funcione con _SharpDevelop_. ¿Habrá alguna manera de cambiar de compilador? De ese modo, al menos puedo saber por qué me tira ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, no es posible.

No es posible compilar *.Net CLI* en *SharpDevelop* porque el código está escrito en ***C# 7*** y *SharpDevelop* solo soporta desde ***C# 2*** hasta ***C# 5*** inclusive.

Habría que esperar actualizaciones. Una alternativa puede ser usar otro *IDE*.